# how to extract this firmware .img?

Tags: firmware, binwalk

how to extract this firmware .img?!?

https://files.fm/u/bhgbk336r

w/ **binwalk** i've this output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
64            0x40            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65462 bytes
10019         0x2723          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65527 bytes
17145         0x42F9          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65523 bytes
27201         0x6A41          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65517 bytes
36189         0x8D5D          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65530 bytes
47203         0xB863          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65503 bytes
55802         0xD9FA          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65511 bytes
66294         0x102F6         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65530 bytes
74373         0x12285         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65513 bytes
84641         0x14AA1         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65491 bytes
96120         0x17778         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65531 bytes
107487        0x1A3DF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65490 bytes
118228        0x1CDD4         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 65511 bytes
128486        0x1F5E6         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 12443 bytes
131629        0x2022D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2609 bytes
132847        0x206EF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 18233 bytes
138302        0x21C3E         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 41608 bytes
151183        0x24E8F         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 33777 bytes
162123        0x2794B         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 10280 bytes
166272        0x28980         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 7433 bytes
169162        0x294CA         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 9458 bytes
172881        0x2A351         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 9317 bytes
176289        0x2B0A1         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 13027 bytes
180676        0x2C1C4         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 15128 bytes
185960        0x2D668         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 13617 bytes
190742        0x2E916         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5538 bytes
192991        0x2F1DF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 12703 bytes
197453        0x3034D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 759 bytes
197837        0x304CD         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 14104 bytes
203149        0x3198D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 9155 bytes
206550        0x326D6         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 19024 bytes
213531        0x3421B         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6917 bytes
215791        0x34AEF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5125 bytes
217913        0x35339         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 27069 bytes
226895        0x3764F         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 43531 bytes
240883        0x3ACF3         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3854 bytes
242610        0x3B3B2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 33522 bytes
252035        0x3D883         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 23064 bytes
259561        0x3F5E9         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3899 bytes
261296        0x3FCB0         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1511 bytes
262034        0x3FF92         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 965 bytes
262637        0x401ED         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6289 bytes
264930        0x40AE2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 996 bytes
265497        0x40D19         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1347 bytes
266128        0x40F90         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 146 bytes
266260        0x41014         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 146 bytes
266496        0x41100         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3273 bytes
268276        0x417F4         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 202 bytes
268442        0x4189A         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 799 bytes
268943        0x41A8F         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 146 bytes
269075        0x41B13         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1429 bytes
269803        0x41DEB         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1868 bytes
270640        0x42130         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 308 bytes
270822        0x421E6         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 590 bytes
271145        0x42329         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 768 bytes
271639        0x42517         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 796 bytes
272135        0x42707         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1369 bytes
272899        0x42A03         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5221 bytes
275030        0x43256         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2726 bytes
276220        0x436FC         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1695 bytes
277144        0x43A98         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 7771 bytes
279560        0x44408         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 146 bytes
279692        0x4448C         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2744 bytes
280921        0x44959         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1276 bytes
281583        0x44BEF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3616 bytes
283048        0x451A8         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1311 bytes
283576        0x453B8         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1170 bytes
284166        0x45606         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1182 bytes
284756        0x45854         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1182 bytes
285346        0x45AA2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 753 bytes
285820        0x45C7C         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1377 bytes
286373        0x45EA5         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2232 bytes
287357        0x4627D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2051 bytes
288351        0x4665F         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 561 bytes
288725        0x467D5         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 146 bytes
288857        0x46859         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 722 bytes
289327        0x46A2F         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 99 bytes
289418        0x46A8A         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1288 bytes
290001        0x46CD1         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2234 bytes
290928        0x47070         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3571 bytes
292378        0x4761A         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4966 bytes
294338        0x47DC2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2096 bytes
295328        0x481A0         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6572 bytes
297936        0x48BD0         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6438 bytes
300568        0x49618         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2304 bytes
301760        0x49AC0         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6179 bytes
303964        0x4A35C         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1866 bytes
304803        0x4A6A3         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2963 bytes
305922        0x4AB02         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 7477 bytes
308178        0x4B3D2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 7477 bytes
310439        0x4BCA7         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1775 bytes
311263        0x4BFDF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1632 bytes
312030        0x4C2DE         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4224 bytes
313686        0x4C956         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1153 bytes
314414        0x4CC2E         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5012 bytes
316158        0x4D2FE         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 488 bytes
316482        0x4D442         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 488 bytes
317170        0x4D6F2         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 51062 bytes
332889        0x51459         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2749 bytes
333949        0x5187D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4651 bytes
335686        0x51F46         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 6097 bytes
337739        0x5274B         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4053 bytes
339762        0x52F32         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3697 bytes
341293        0x5352D         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1192 bytes
341816        0x53738         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2243 bytes
343029        0x53BF5         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2170 bytes
344119        0x54037         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 9547 bytes
347922        0x54F12         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 853 bytes
348334        0x550AE         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5375 bytes
350578        0x55972         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 293 bytes
350820        0x55A64         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 9203 bytes
354193        0x56791         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1635 bytes
355082        0x56B0A         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2386 bytes
356351        0x56FFF         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 711 bytes
356748        0x5718C         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 648 bytes
357145        0x57319         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 677 bytes
357515        0x5748B         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 439 bytes
357712        0x57550         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 335 bytes
357966        0x5764E         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 806 bytes
358456        0x57838         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 943 bytes
358927        0x57A0F         GIF image data, version "89a", 135 x 22
359664        0x57CF0         GIF image data, version "89a", 135 x 22
360741        0x58125         GIF image data, version "89a", 220 x 22
361644        0x584AC         GIF image data, version "89a", 200 x 22
362555        0x5883B         GIF image data, version "89a", 285 x 1
362630        0x58886         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 28
363147        0x58A8B         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 45
363899        0x58D7B         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 60
364866        0x59142         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 28
367685        0x59C45         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 45
371953        0x5ACF1         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 60
375470        0x5BAAE         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 28
375997        0x5BCBD         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 45
376943        0x5C06F         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 60
378366        0x5C5FE         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 28
379005        0x5C87D         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 45
379714        0x5CB42         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 28
380346        0x5CDBA         GIF image data, version "89a", 182 x 45
381053        0x5D07D         GIF image data, version "89a", 605 x 1
381136        0x5D0D0         GIF image data, version "89a", 170 x 42
381348        0x5D1A4         GIF image data, version "89a", 170 x 60
381614        0x5D2AE         GIF image data, version "89a", 169 x 26
381773        0x5D34D         GIF image data, version "89a", 295 x 271
384103        0x5DC67         GIF image data, version "89a", 23 x 23
384298        0x5DD2A         GIF image data, version "89a", 20 x 20
384708        0x5DEC4         GIF image data, version "89a", 24 x 22
385099        0x5E04B         GIF image data, version "89a", 295 x 34
385291        0x5E10B         GIF image data, version "89a", 131 x 22
385976        0x5E3B8         GIF image data, version "89a", 599 x 210
388759        0x5EE97         GIF image data, version "89a", 192 x 192
393237        0x60015         GIF image data, version "89a", 186 x 36
394236        0x603FC         GIF image data, version "89a", 192 x 192
400870        0x61DE6         GIF image data, version "89a", 176 x 2
400942        0x61E2E         GIF image data, version "89a", 192 x 192
405140        0x62E94         GIF image data, version "89a", 186 x 36
405812        0x63134         GIF image data, version "89a", 47 x 45
406661        0x63485         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 29
409465        0x63F79         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 58
413125        0x64DC5         GIF image data, version "89a", 191 x 27
413819        0x6507B         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 29
414503        0x65327         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 58
415868        0x6587C         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 50
416324        0x65A44         GIF image data, version "89a", 147 x 22
417280        0x65E00         GIF image data, version "89a", 147 x 22
418104        0x66138         GIF image data, version "89a", 99 x 22
418555        0x662FB         GIF image data, version "89a", 124 x 22
419214        0x6658E         GIF image data, version "89a", 147 x 22
420170        0x6694A         GIF image data, version "89a", 242 x 41
423298        0x67582         GIF image data, version "89a", 131 x 22
424314        0x6797A         GIF image data, version "89a", 175 x 22
425455        0x67DEF         GIF image data, version "89a", 147 x 22
426686        0x682BE         GIF image data, version "89a", 190 x 22
427866        0x6875A         GIF image data, version "89a", 135 x 22
428885        0x68B55         GIF image data, version "89a", 47 x 45
429716        0x68E94         GIF image data, version "89a", 1636 x 83
430329        0x690F9         GIF image data, version "89a", 818 x 83
432720        0x69A50         GIF image data, version "89a", 46 x 13
432966        0x69B46         GIF image data, version "89a", 45 x 12
433329        0x69CB1         GIF image data, version "89a", 618 x 25
434251        0x6A04B         GIF image data, version "89a", 20 x 21
434929        0x6A2F1         GIF image data, version "89a", 120 x 31
435048        0x6A368         GIF image data, version "89a", 200 x 31
435189        0x6A3F5         GIF image data, version "89a", 220 x 31
435335        0x6A487         GIF image data, version "89a", 160 x 31
435466        0x6A50A         GIF image data, version "89a", 120 x 31
435585        0x6A581         GIF image data, version "89a", 200 x 31
435726        0x6A60E         GIF image data, version "89a", 220 x 31
435872        0x6A6A0         GIF image data, version "89a", 160 x 31
436003        0x6A723         GIF image data, version "89a", 16 x 12
436067        0x6A763         GIF image data, version "87a", 371 x 38
440721        0x6B991         GIF image data, version "89a", 320 x 22
441762        0x6BDA2         GIF image data, version "89a", 320 x 22
442886        0x6C206         GIF image data, version "89a", 125 x 22
443571        0x6C4B3         GIF image data, version "89a", 7 x 7
443741        0x6C55D         GIF image data, version "89a", 39 x 22
444060        0x6C69C         GIF image data, version "89a", 95 x 22
444502        0x6C856         GIF image data, version "89a", 65 x 22
444868        0x6C9C4         GIF image data, version "89a", 157 x 27
445711        0x6CD0F         GIF image data, version "89a", 152 x 23
446606        0x6D08E         GIF image data, version "89a", 1 x 1
446649        0x6D0B9         GIF image data, version "89a", 99 x 22
447100        0x6D27C         GIF image data, version "89a", 16 x 2
447152        0x6D2B0         GIF image data, version "89a", 24 x 23
447906        0x6D5A2         GIF image data, version "89a", 8 x 23
448114        0x6D672         GIF image data, version "89a", 10 x 23
448449        0x6D7C1         GIF image data, version "89a", 1 x 97
448498        0x6D7F2         GIF image data, version "89a", 30 x 30
454835        0x6F0B3         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
454865        0x6F0D1         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
456342        0x6F696         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
457912        0x6FCB8         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
459560        0x70328         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
461071        0x7090F         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
461101        0x7092D         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
462957        0x7106D         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
462987        0x7108B         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
464892        0x717FC         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
464922        0x7181A         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
466799        0x71F6F         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
468465        0x725F1         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
468495        0x7260F         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
470431        0x72D9F         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
470461        0x72DBD         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
472478        0x7359E         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
474586        0x73DDA         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
476701        0x7461D         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
476731        0x7463B         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
478855        0x74E87         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
478885        0x74EA5         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
481212        0x757BC         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
481242        0x757DA         TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
483575        0x760F7         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
484861        0x765FD         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
486220        0x76B4C         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
487649        0x770E1         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
488663        0x774D7         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
489587        0x77873         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
490506        0x77C0A         JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
```

w/ **binwalk -E** i've this output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Rising entropy edge (0.971396)
267264        0x41400         Falling entropy edge (0.749340)
268288        0x41800         Rising entropy edge (0.965116)
316416        0x4D400         Falling entropy edge (0.817658)
317440        0x4D800         Rising entropy edge (0.974117)
364544        0x59000         Falling entropy edge (0.712331)
367616        0x59C00         Falling entropy edge (0.788928)
368640        0x5A000         Rising entropy edge (0.955394)
371712        0x5AC00         Falling entropy edge (0.669882)
372736        0x5B000         Rising entropy edge (0.962893)
381952        0x5D400         Rising entropy edge (0.951576)
390144        0x5F400         Rising entropy edge (0.959505)
401408        0x62000         Rising entropy edge (0.957726)
406528        0x63400         Falling entropy edge (0.751087)
407552        0x63800         Rising entropy edge (0.962352)
409600        0x64000         Falling entropy edge (0.835638)
410624        0x64400         Rising entropy edge (0.961142)
415744        0x65800         Falling entropy edge (0.838426)
419840        0x66800         Falling entropy edge (0.837450)
421888        0x67000         Rising entropy edge (0.951411)
425984        0x68000         Rising entropy edge (0.956190)
428032        0x68800         Falling entropy edge (0.845137)
430080        0x69000         Rising entropy edge (0.954675)
435200        0x6A400         Falling entropy edge (0.824996)
436224        0x6A800         Rising entropy edge (0.959224)
448512        0x6D800         Rising entropy edge (0.977768)
460800        0x70800         Falling entropy edge (0.776163)
462848        0x71000         Falling entropy edge (0.806674)
464896        0x71800         Falling entropy edge (0.847345)
468992        0x72800         Rising entropy edge (0.952799)
476160        0x74400         Falling entropy edge (0.823714)
479232        0x75000         Falling entropy edge (0.846434)
481280        0x75800         Falling entropy edge (0.827863)
491520        0x78000         Rising entropy edge (0.973460)
1926144       0x1D6400        Falling entropy edge (0.646491)
```

and this graph:
[image]
[image]

w/ **dd if=firmware.img of=firmware.lzma skip=xx count=xxxxx bs=1** obtain only .lzma corrupted files

w/ **binwalk -e** obtain only numeric files + same numeric files on .7z archives

my goal is extract (also only listing) all .htm files on /www folder

Comment: What is the target device?
How did you get this file? Is this dump from some storage device like PROM, NAND, etc., or you downloaded it from producer web-site?
Why do you think that this file is firmware?
Plz give us more info..

Comment: device is a modem router Netgear D1500 w/ stock firmware v1.0.0.25_1.0.1PE (EU except UK/AU), i've repack my .zip file uploaded from original .zip official producer update at this direct link: https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/D1500/D1500-V1.0.0.25_1.0.1PE.zip
last Netgear devices use .img extension for binary firmware/updates, but in this case w/o squashfs

Comment: Looks like binwalk is providing false positives for file type, so it won't extract the firmware correctly.  I would guess it is compressed, so LZMA looks right, but it might also be encrypted.  Have you run `strings` on the blob and carefully looked at the readable strings to determine any other useful information about the image?  Is it an RTOS blob, linux, or bare metal firmware?  You might also look for break points in the binary where long blocks of zeros are followed by data -- those may be good points to DD the original file apart.

Answer (score 1):

I unpacked this stuff with binwalk -e <file_name> and got list of files like:
1A3DF
1CDD4
1F5E6
...

Their content looks like some web-document with images:

**Static Routes Help**

Static routes give the router information that it cannot learn automatically through other means. This can happen when RIP is disabled on the LAN. (See the LAN IP Setup screen.) All defined static routes appear in the table. You add or delete a route in the area under the Static Routes table.

---

[image]

I haven't analyzed all files, you may do it yourself.
But I haven't seen any stuff which looks like firmware in this files.